# Boto3 " KeyError: 'AccessKeyId' ". Fixed, but not sure how

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, boto3

I have two AWS accounts that send email from an EC2 instance. Each EC2 instance has a role that allows them to perform the action `ses:SendRawEmail` and each instance uses the boto3 python module. Both of these instances worked, until out of nowhere, they both failed at this line in the python code:

```
client=boto3.client('ses','us-east-1')
```

and with the following error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/utils.py", line 203, in retrieve_iam_role_credentials
    'access_key': data[role_name]['AccessKeyId'],
KeyError: 'AccessKeyId'
```

I navigated to the `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/` directory and opened the `utils.py` file with vim. I navigated to the `retrieve_iam_role_credentials` method and attempted to insert a print statement in the `role_name` loop. I received an "attempting to write in a read only file" error, then exited with the command `:q!`.

The strange thing is, that when I attempted to run the send email code again, it was successful. I did not think that this had solved the problem, but when I repeated the same steps on the other EC2 instance it also started working.

I guess my question is what was the problem, and how did I fix it?

Comment: I have seen this very intermittently in sqs/s3, `KeyError: 'access_key'` with a role. My bet/hack is that wrapping each call in a try/sleep a few times block will make this work every time. Kinda sucks boto3 doesn't handle it.

Comment: It's perhaps also possible/worth noting, that this could arise from handware/os dropping packets, as this seems to also be an issue for us on these machines (AWS support have confirmed there is an issue). Hence the sleep+retry.